# jQuery AJAX help

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new here, and I have looked at the other Ajax Help topics, however, I still can't see why mine isn't working.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "localhost/val.php",
        data: "val=RichieC",
        success: function(msg){
            alert("WOO");
        }
    });
});
```

Has anyone got any ideas? I've tried a few things!

Thanks!

Comment: Any error messages?  What exactly is 'not working'?

Comment: Which part isn't working?.. Is the success callback just not firing?  Have you tried adding an error callback and see if it gets called?

Comment: Can you post an example of the data coming back?  If the data coming back is not valid then jQuery will tend to discard it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting `http://localhost/val.php` in the url. The way it is now will look for a `localhost` folder in the current directory.

Comment: yeah, because in userxxx's example it actually tries to call ` http://www.example.org/localhost/val.php `

Comment: Fantastic, Did exactly what I needed it to! :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you debug val.php and verify that your server side code is running when you make the AJAX call? If your action is executing, you can make sure everything is working as expected by just stepping through (or alternatively, as Quintin Robinson suggested, you could add a failure callback to see if that is being called).

If your action is doing what you think it should do and still no callbacks are firing, well, that one's a toughie :)

Comment: Thanks! However, the val.php was only very simple, it was only a test script. I'm just trying to get the hang of AJAX and jQuery :) But thanks anyways!